# Angular - Getting result as "Null" from backend

Tags: angular, api, angular-httpclient

I'm trying to pull datas from "http://169.38.82.132:94/GetFarmerInfo" to "http://localhost:4200/". First I need to create a token and pass the same to the above URL to get the datas to be displayed in the required format. I have created a toke using "fetchPeople()" and passed the same as "this.token" in "fetchFarmerDetails(Venktoken:string)". Everything is working fine but am getting the farmerdetails as null, please let me know if any changes has to done to get the needed results.

```
//people.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse ,HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })

export class PeopleService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { } 

  token:string;

  fetchPeople() {       
      let url = "http://169.38.82.132:94/token";    
      var data = "grant_type=password&username=user&password=user";
  return this.http.post( url, data,
    {headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    })}  
    )
    };   

    fetchFarmerDetails(Venktoken:string) {
      console.log("Welcome");
      console.log(Venktoken);
      this.token = Venktoken;    
      console.log(this.token);
     let url = "http://169.38.82.132:94/GetFarmerInfo";     
     var data1 = "'InstanceName': 'ORISSA'";
let headers = new HttpHeaders()
.set("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + this.token)
.set('Content-Type','application/json');
     return this.http.post(url, data1, {headers:headers});     
    };

  }
```

in the above code am getting the token and am passing the same to "fetchFarmerDetails(Venktoken:string)", in console the token gets displays.

```
app.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { PeopleService } from './people.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  people$;
  name:string;
  Temp_token: string;
  title = 'demojsontable';
  constructor(private peopleService:PeopleService,private http:HttpClient){

  }
  fetchPeople() {
    this.peopleService.fetchPeople().subscribe((res:any)=>{      
      console.log(res);
      this.Temp_token= res.access_token;      
      console.log(this.Temp_token); 
      this.fetchFarmerDetails();     
    });
  }

  fetchFarmerDetails(){  

    this.peopleService.fetchFarmerDetails(this.Temp_token).subscribe((resp:any)=>{         
    console.log(resp);   
    this.people$ = resp.FarmerDetails;
    });
   }

}
```

and finally i need to display the result in tabular form for that am using the below code

```
app.component.html
<!--<app-datas></app-datas>-->
<button (click)="fetchPeople()">Fetch People</button>

<hr>
<table border="1">
    <thead>       
            <td>Farmer Code</td> 
            <td>Farmer Name<td>  

    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let person of people$|async">
        <td>{{person.FarmerName}}</td> 
        <td>{{person.FarmerCode}}</td>        
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

First am trying to get farmername and farmer code alone. Please help me to achieve this.

Comment: You mean getting null here ```console.log(resp);``` ?

Comment: Do you get any error in console/network tab in your developer tool regarding the api call??

Comment: Also can you try changing the ```var data1 = "'InstanceName': 'ORISSA'"; ```  variable declaration to  
  ```var data1 = {InstanceName:'ORISSA'}``` it should be an object like this..

Comment: Great !!!! I got it Thanks @Maniraj Murugan, can you please tell how to get farmername and code in frontend am using the code in app.component.html

Comment: What I need to see is your exact data that you get in ```console.log(resp); ```, so that I can find out how it can be displayed in ```HTML```  template.. Can you post the data that you receive in ```resp``` ??

Comment: am posting the console response in the link - http://sampledemos.online/image/console.png

Comment: If this was the response, then your actual code itself should work.. Can you try giving ```{{people$.length}}``` before this line, ```<tr *ngFor="let person of people$|async">``` and let me know whether it gives length of the array..

Comment: Okay try ```console.log(this.people$)``` in ```ts``` file after this line,  ```this.people$ = resp.FarmerDetails;``` ..

Comment: Also in ```app.component.ts``` you need to give initialization like, ```people$: any[] = [];``` and not ```people$;``` .. Try changing this line..

Comment: Thanks got it by updating the code as <tr *ngFor="let person of people$"> in app.component.html

Comment: I am not sure why you are using ```async``` pipe here.. try removing async pipe and just give, ```<tr *ngFor="let person of people$>``` alone..

Comment: Yes I removed and it is working, thanks for your valuable comments

Comment: Okay Venkat I will post it as an answer, feel free to accept it if it solves your issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First issue is in the file, `people.service.ts`,

```
fetchFarmerDetails(Venktoken:string) {
     .
     .
     .
     var data1 = "'InstanceName': 'ORISSA'";
     .
     .
     return this.http.post(url, data1, {headers:headers});     
};
```

While you using [this.http.post()](https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request), the second argument (body) which you passing is invalid, rather you should pass it as an object like,

```
var data1 = {InstanceName:'ORISSA'}
```

Next, in `app.component.ts`,

change `people$;`  **to**   `people$: any[] = [];`

Even though it works with `people$;`, follow the syntax for defining array types in TypeScript.

You need to initialize the type of data for `$people` here..

Also in `app.component.html`,

Change  `<tr *ngFor="let person of people$|async">` **to** `<tr *ngFor="let person of people$>`

Unless you are using observable array don't use `async` pipe..

Comment: Without changing people$; to people$: any[] = [];it is working fine and thanks for your support and guidance.

Comment: @Venkat, It will work though but I would suggest to  follow the syntax for defining array types in TypeScript..

Comment: @Venkat, Also I would suggest you to replace ```var``` keyword with ```const``` because I am seeing nowhere you are reassigning the value to a variable with ```var``` keyword.. Even though you want to reassign, you can use ```let``` keyword.. Everything in your code will work but your code will be neat if you follow some best practices bro tats it..

Comment: Okay @Maniraj Murugan